Examples of Persistent Homology Calculation Using Spectral Sequences
Hello Math Exchange community,
I am currently studying persistent homology and am particularly interested in how spectral sequences can be applied to this area. However, I've struggled to find comprehensive resources online that provide step-by-step calculations.
I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide examples of calculating persistent homology using spectral sequences. Specifically, I'm looking for:
An easy example that clearly illustrates the process.
A more complicated example that involves infinity pages.
If possible, please include all the details and explanations at each step of the calculations. I believe this would be beneficial not only for me but for others in the community who are learning about this topic.
Thank you in advance for your help!
